# How does 'group as' work in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I'm having trouble understanding how `group by group_name` works in a `foreach` loop.

Let's say we already have a variable named `grouped_data` that was defined as:

```
grouped_data = group dataset by (emp_id, dept_id);
```

And then we want to iterate over each record in `grouped_data` with an aggregated column added in. So the following is written:

```
with_hours_worked = FOREACH grouped_data 
                    GENERATE group AS grp, 
                             SUM(dataset.worked_hours) AS hours ;
```

I'm confused as to what is going on in that last line, especially the `group AS grp` part. Is `grp` a tuple? Is the line from `grouped_data` converted back into a group? If so, why?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you use `group by` in Pig, for each of the groups a new register consisting of two parts is created: the first part is a tuple containing the values you grouped by, and the second one a bag containing all the values of that group.

For example, if you have the following data:

```
user_id, dept_id, blah_1, blah_2
1,41,pig,mapreduce
1,41,spark,apache
2,30,oh,yeah
```

After grouping by user_id and dept_id, you will have the following:

```
(1,41),{(pig,mapreduce),(spark,apache)}
(2,30),{(oh,yeah)}
```

The first part is what Pig calls `group`, the tuple containing in this case `user_id` and `dept_id`. The `group as grp` just renames it to `grp`... Not a great name but that's what that code is doing!

Comment: Here is the relevant page in the [documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/basic.html#group).